# How to set a spring datasource url to a resources folder?

Tags: spring-boot

I have a hsqldb file in my project resources folrder  "src/main/resources/mydb.data"

In my application.properites I need to set the path with spring.datasource.url=

How I can achieve that?

spring.datasource.url=.... ?

Comment: There is no `src/main/resources` when running the application, there is only the class path. So this won't  work, simply because you wouldn't be able to store anything inside the database as that would be modifying a class within the packaged jar/war.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use Maven resource filtering. Just use something like this in your `application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:hsqldb:file:@basedir@/src/main/resources/mydb.data
```

Instead of using `basedir` you can define something like `darasource-url` in your `pom.xml` and use this property in your `application.properties`:

**pom.xml**

```
<project>
  <!-- ... -->
  <properties>
    <datasource-url>jdbc:hsqldb:file:${basedir}/src/main/resources/mydb.data</datasource-url>
  </properties>
  <!-- ... -->
</project>
```

**application.properties**:

```
spring.datasource.url=@datasource-url@
```

---

Notice: Using the spring-boot-starter-parent as parent, you have to use `@..@` instead of `${..}`, see [2.1.1. Automatic Property Expansion Using Maven](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-automatic-expansion-maven) in the Spring Boot How-to-Guides.

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:hsqldb::resource:mydb.data
```